# IBM Websphere SSO and LTPA Token

Tags: security, websphere, single-sign-on, token

I have enable SSO(Single Sign-On) between two Websphere application server and both administrative console is open with SSO .

I have created a web application which has form based authentication,it successfully validate the user from LDAP,but the application is not setting LTPA cookies.What is the issue because it should return LTPA tokens.

Comment: How you can tell that the token is not set? If you successfully logged in to application and are browsing it then the token is set (check the cookies in the browser you should have LTPAToken2 there). What problem you observe? And what is your user registry configuration on both servers (Standalone LDAP or federated)?

Comment: Basically when i see network of the browser i dont see LtpaToken and LtpaToken2 in the cookies,i see JSession and other cookies.I am using LDAP

Comment: LtpaToken2 cookie would only not be generated, if you would disable SSO in Web and Sip Security or changed its default name.
Which WAS version are you using? Check, if cookies are visible in FF.

Comment: I am using was 8.5 and i am enable sso and named LtpaToken and LtpaToken2 in SSO.

Comment: Is SSO not working? Any exceptions in SystemOut.logs? Please better describe your problem.